# Glitch with multiple accordions within tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have just looked through all similar posts on StackOverflow about this issue.

Previously, these were working fine on this site because an ID was being used for every different accordion. The problem is we use this script across multiple sites and have 20+ scripts that are nearly identical with just the ID change was getting annoying.

I changed the scripts from:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                        
        $('#MANYDIFFERENTIDNAMES').accordion({              
            handle: ".handle",
            panel: ".panel",
            canToggle: true,
            activeClassLi: "active",
            speed: 600            
        });
    });
</script>
```

To one single script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                        
        $('.accordion').accordion({              
            handle: ".handle",
            panel: ".panel",
            canToggle: true,
            activeClassLi: "active",
            speed: 600            
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see from the page in question (http://servicetechnology.ecisolutions.com/solutions/e-automate-overview.aspx) the script still seems to work in each tab with each accordion, but there is a glitch (there is a delay and no transition on open), on opening when multiple accordions are on the page.

There are no glitches, of course, when only one accordion is on the page. You can see the smooth open transition on a page like this: http://lbmh.ecisolutions.com/advantage/solutions.aspx

Any idea what is causing this glitch when there are multiple accordions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page with multiple accordions also includes the accordion initialization script multiple times, which shouldn't be the case. You only need *one* script which initializes them. The selector `.accordion` selects *all* elements on the page with `class="accordion"`.